# adding _header.html.erb to static html pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a _header.html.erb file which includes the logo and other text fields.
How can I add it to static html pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the high voltage gem to get a bit more ruby into your static content: https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage